# Django Caching - How do I set up my code to avoid duplicating cache logic?

Tags: django, caching

I started profiling my app and discovered that there's a piece of code that takes a significantly longer amount of time to complete than others. In the view, I'm retrieving some data from a database and transforming it a little bit. In the template, there's a filter that will take this transformed data and convert into a HTML.

I realized that I could leverage caching since this component does not change that frequently but I'm wondering what the best way to do it is. I can cache both the results of the database call/transform but I can also cache the template fragment. It seems odd that I'd need to cache  two things to get the best effect so I imagine my code should have been structured differently so I would only need to cache the data in one location.

One idea I had is to do the database call from within the template filter function but I've been trying to keep my model code outside of my template filters.

What is the best way to handle this sort of problem?

Answer (score 1):

If the transformation can be represented as complex queryset, you could evaluate it in template w/o caching in view. If not, you could

- do the logic in template tag inside cache block
- wrap logic and pass it to render, typically in the form of closure or model method
- only do view cache, as long as rendering process is simple
- check possibility of SSI w/ help of TemplateResponse
- write code to check-and-use template cache in view, w/ considering of possible race-write and dog-pile issue.

Furthermore, for queryset cache, you could try [johnny-cache](http://packages.python.org/johnny-cache/), as well as [django-cache-machine](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-cache-machine).

Comment: Unfortunately the transforming is a bit more complicated and needs to be done in code at the moment - it's also doing it outside of Django's ORM since I'm working with MongoDB on this. One approach is to have that method also generate the html code and then pass that into the template. This seems kind of sketchy but I also don't want to be making Mongo calls from a template tag. Unfortunately, neither of these seem particularly elegant to me but I imagine I will go with having the logic being done in the template tag.

Comment: Do you mind to paste some code so we can see how do you use MongoDB from the view? Usually is not a good idea to move logic to a template tag.

Comment: Well in Django the view is the controller. I'm just doing a map-reduce call and caching the results of that per user.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cache in the view AND in the template fragment. The idea of caching is, once you've something cached, you get it from cache until the cache key expires.

Caching the database results in the view implies writing some code specific for the view logic, that you'd probably need to change every time the logic changes.

Caching the template fragment is a better approach, because even if you change the template "logic", as long as you keep the fragment inside a cached block, the caching will continue working.

Also IMHO, the more close to the final response you cache, the more reliable the cache logic will be.

Comment: Yea - I understand the point that's why I want to minimize it. Unfortunately if I only cache the template fragment then the view will still be making a call to the database to retrieve the data since at that point it doesn't know that the template fragment where it will be used is already cached. How can I structure the project to deal with that?

Comment: If you want to have the cache handling in one location, you can use a django caching middleware to cache the requests, and supposing  that fragment need to be cached more often, use a different timeout for the general cache and for the template fragment.

Comment: Yea - I ended up refactoring the code to have the template fragment either retrieved from cache or calculated in the view so it's all done in one place.